# Assume that the set of values where $f^{(k)}≠0$ is finite

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, roots, analyticity

Let $f:ℝ→ℝ$ be a real analytic function. Let $f^{(k)}$ be the $k$th derivative of $f$. Assume that the set of values where $f^{(k)}≠0$ is finite, then what we can say about the function $f$.

Comment: So $k$ is fixed?

Comment: Or the set of values of k is being  referred to?

Comment: @ShaneORourke: Yes, $k$ is fixed.

Comment: So $f^{(k)}=0$ on the complement of this finite set, which is a finite union of open intervals. What does this tell you about $f^{(k-1)}$ in view of the mvt? Etc...

Comment: @julien: this means that $f$ is identically zero.

Comment: No. This means that the k-1 derivative is zero. So f is a polynomial of degree not greater than k-2.

Comment: @julien: Yes and thank you very much.

Comment: @julien: So, what happen if the set of values where $f^{(k)}≠0$ is infinite

Comment: Well, that's a different question. Then it could be $\mathbb{R}$ and there is nothing you can deduce without further assumptions on $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is that derivatives have the intermediate value property. That is, if $g$ is differentiable on an open interval $I$ and $g'(a)<\alpha<g'(c)$ for some $a,c\in I$ then there exists $b\in(a,c)$ such that $g'(b)=\alpha$. So if $g'$ takes only finitely many values on $I$, this is pretty strong information which should enable you to find a simple description of $g$.

Then to deal with $f^{(k)}$, just take $g=f^{(k-1)}$ in the previous paragraph to get a description of $f^{(k-1)}$. Then integrate repeatedly to find $f$. (And don't worry, $f^{(k-1)}$ will be integrable.)

Comment: The intermediate value property of a derivative is much more difficult than the mean value theorem. And that s all you need here.